# Ruby on Rails: CarrierWave - Associate model.id with a different model (foreign key)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I have a model for Brochures. Brochures belong to a property. Properties allow the uploading of brochures (pdf files).

Brochure Model:

```
class Brochure < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :property

  mount_uploader :document, BrochuresUploader
end
```

Inside my `properties_controller` file and `update` method, after the property update, it's calling:

```
def update
    find_property
    authorize! :update, @property


...
    if @property.update(property_params)
      brochure_service = BrochureService.new(@property)
      brochure_service.add_brochures(params[:property][:brochures], [])
      brochure_service.remove_marked_brochures

      flash[:notice] = "Listing edited successfully"
      redirect_to action: :show
    ...
```

So it's calling a Brochure service method:

```
  def add_brochures(new_brochures, removed_brochures)

    new_brochures&.pop

    removed_brochures = removed_brochures&.split(',')

    new_brochures&.each do |brochure|
      next if removed_brochures.include?(brochure.original_filename)
      @property.brochures.create(document: brochure)
    end
  end
```

The `BrochureUploader` that inherits `CarrerWave::Uploader::base` has this method:

```
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

The problem here is the `model.id`

When brochures are uploaded, they get put inside a incrementing folder name like `1` `2` `3`.

They're supposed to be put in a folder based on the property ID, like `57`.

I'm not sure how to pass that property id into this uploader.

If you need any more information, let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to access the property on the model like so:

`#{model.property.id}`

Model referring to Brochure. Brochure has access to the `property` since it `belongs_to`